# How does git-cherry knows which commits have been incorporated into the upstream branch?

Tags: git

I'm Curious to know what is the 'git-cherry' (equivalent to 'git cherry') algorithm.
Suppose I'm on topic branch that branched out of master, and it has some new commits A,B,C.
Lets say B was cherry picked into master

```
master--D-E-B
 \
  \-topic-A-B-C
```

This will let me know which of A,B,C have been cherry-picked into master. In this case, B was.

```
git checkout topic
git cherry origin/master
+A
-B
+C
```

How does 'git cherry' knows that? what is the algorithm and metadata used here and where it is stored?
It could have calculated a hash of 'commit B diff' and check that the exact commit diff hash is present in master. But what about non trivial merges? the commit diff will not be the same.

Thanks,

Comment: Great question, my guess is that the cherry picked commit maintains a small bit of metadata with this information.  @torek will give you a better answer, I'm certain.

Comment: What about what the docs say? 
“The equivalence test is based on the diff, after removing whitespace and line numbers.”

Answer (score 1):

`git cherry` is a front end that makes the more complicated—and slightly less capable—`git rev-list --cherry-mark` output more useful (and avoids the need for a symmetric difference argument; see below).

The way `git rev-list --cherry-mark` works is much as you suggested:

> [Git] could have calculated a hash of 'commit B diff' and check that the exact commit diff hash is present in master.

This is called a *patch-id* and there is a Git program to generate it, which is naturally called `git patch-id`.  Since Git 1.9, there are two types of patch ID available, as described in [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-patch-id).

> But what about non trivial merges?

Here, the patch-ID tends not to match, so Git considers these different commits.  That is probably what we want since the merge itself *was* nontrivial (i.e., required manual resolution).

Note that when using `git rev-list --cherry-mark` you *must* select the symmetric difference option using the three-dot notation (see [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions)).  The commits that have patch-IDs calculated are those from the left and right "sides" of the symmetric difference.  The `git cherry` command produces the appropriate revision lists internally, from the upstream, head, and limit arguments.